# Why is a "list" of values associated with a variable (e.g. X1, X2, ... , Xn) often called variables (plural)?

Tags: probability, statistics, vectors, random-variables, terminology

One of the most common beginnings of any statistics or probability proofs goes something like:

```
let X = (X1, X2, ... ,Xn) be a random vector with the variables assumed to be drawn from a multivariate Gaussian.
```

...or something along these lines. The list of values (X1, X2, ... ,Xn) are being called variable(s), plural. But isn't this in fact ONE variable only, and the subscript versions are the various values that have been drawn for that ONE variable?

Why is the list of values being called variables?

[image]

Comment: Solve $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}$. Is $x$ a variable?

Comment: The term "variable" simply means a placeholder whose value is allowed to vary, ie, it can take on literal values from some set. So, yes, the $X_k$'s are variables as well; they can take on values from a multivariate gaussian distribution in this case. And $X$ is also a vector variable whose _components_ are variables $X_i$ (this seems to be a terminological issue rather than a mathematical issue)

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I see. I guess I was thinking of variable as a feature (an attribute of some phenomenon that is measured, like temperature). But as you say, variables are used to represent an arbitrary element of a set, and can be either the vector itself (e.g. some overall attribute of an object, like temperature measured on different occasions) or the values that comprise that vector.

Comment: Yes, since the values of $X_i$ vary, $X$ varies as well. Also, they need not represent observable/measurable physical attributes, even in physics. For example, there are physical theories using [hidden variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-variable_theory). I like to think of variables from a math/programming perspective since the idea is more general there (for example, an `int` variable takes integer values, `float` takes decimal values, etc). Also, the context suggests your example statement means the $X_i$'s are simply gaussian RVs and $X$ is a multivariate gaussian RV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable is something which has (potentially temporarily, if you solve for it) indeterminate value, nothing more, nothing less. That said, it is important to know what your variable *belongs to*.

That is to say, when we have the variable $x$ in the number:

$$3x+12$$

we know from context that in fact, $x$ is a number as well. Let $nX+b = \{nx+b : x \in X\}$. Then we can also have the expression:

$$3X + 12$$

where our variable is a *set*. Now, we do have a few things to say about this. One, we don't really refer to it as a variable in common parlance. Generally, the term 'variable' is reserved for things made of numbers, with some strict definition. That said, that's mostly a convention of convenience and notation, as the essence of an indeterminate identity is what makes variables what they are. Reinforcing this is my second point: we can treat our second formula like the first.

For example, given $y = 3x+12$, we can see that the value of $x$ is determined by the value of $y$. Similarly, given:

$$Y = 3X + 12$$

then $X$ is is totally determined by $Y$; in fact:

$$\frac{1}{3}Y - 4 = X$$

So given a set $Y$ of numbers, we can uniquely determine $X$.

In general, this idea of an indeterminate form is what gives us *generality*. For example, every time a theorem starts with "Let $A$ be a [insert mathematical object here]," we are essentially declaring $A$ to be a "variable" of the form [mathematical object]. Indeed, just as we solve for $x$ given some parameter $y$, many theorems are of the form "Let $A$ be [xyz], and fix some constraints upon it. This implies that $A$ is actually specifically [abc], and only [abc]." That, structurally, is the same as fixing $x$ a random number, saying that some known number $y$ is $3x+12$, and concluding that $x$ must be known as well.

---

More practically, anything that *depends* on a variable is a variable. So let $x$ be a variable, and let:

$$\mathbf{a} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ 123 \end{bmatrix}$$

This is a vector whose value *uniquely depends* on a variable, so in some sense we may write $\mathbf{a}(x)$ as in function notation, and see that $\mathbf{a}$ is a variable exactly in the way that $x$ is: as long as $x$ is a variable, so is $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you.